# Is there a method to get the ace editor by id?

Tags: ace-editor

Is there a method to get a reference to the ace editor by id?

Ace does not keep references to the editor so if I need to get a reference to the editor how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can use the following code:

```
ace.getEditorById = function(el) {
    if (typeof el == "string") {
        var _id = el;
        el = document.getElementById(_id);

        if (!el) {
            return null;
        }

        if (el && el.env && el.env.editor instanceof Editor) {
            return el.env.editor;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I'd like to suggest to add this to core. Maybe we can have an ace.editors dictionary to keep track of them as well. See question [1138](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336542/does-the-ace-core-classes-keep-track-of-all-of-the-editor-instances-on-a-page).

Comment: ace.edit("id") already does that https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.6/lib/ace/ace.js#L84-L85